# Error setting up WebLogic Server 11g (10.3.6): Native Library to read the password securely from commandline is not found

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, server, weblogic11g

Im trying to configure my Weblogic Server in Windows for developers 10.3.6 (11g). From the read me file, I get an error in the following step:

> 5. Create a new WLS domain and start WLS.    (It is recommended that you create the domains outside the MW_HOME) Windows
>      $ mkdir C:\home\myhome\mydomain
>      $ cd C:\home\myhome\mydomain
>      $ %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m weblogic.Server

I successfully create the directory in (C:/WebLogic) and when running the command: `$ %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m weblogic.Server`, I am asked for the username to boot WebLogic, after entering it I get the following error: `<Error><Security><BEA-090783><Server is Running in Development Mode and Native Library<terminalio> to read the password securely from commandline is not found.>`

What can I do to solve this problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This solution](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-workaround-weblogic-terminalio.html) involving adding a weblogic argument to the command line looks like it may solve your problem.

Comment: For the record, in case the linked page ever disappears from the web,  the solution is to add -Dweblogic.management.allowPasswordEcho=true so that you can see the password prompt (you will see the password in the cmd console as you type it in so hide your screen while doing that). Therefore, the full command will be: java.exe -Dweblogic.management.allowPasswordEcho=true %JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m weblogic.Server

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the WebLogic native libraries are not in your PATH.
Change the server environment setup to include the appropriate directory in the PATH. You can set this in WL_HOME%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd (or .sh). Add this after the setting of WL_HOME (example for windows 64 bit):

```
set WL_HOME=C:\wl12120
@REM added the next line
set PATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64;%PATH%
```

After setting up your domain, do the same in your %domain%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd.

Tested for Weblogic 12.1.1 and 12.1.2 zip distribution.

Comment: true, but only for the command session you're doing this from.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the boot.properties file
from: `[PortalDomainRoot]/servers/[AdminServerName]/security/`
to: `[PortalDomainRoot]/servers/[ManagedServerName]/security/`

Or create it yourself and add these two lines at the top:

```
username=<some_username>
password=<some_password>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution (partially thanks to Catweazle's):

Copy terminalio.dll from \server\native\win\x64\terminalio.dll to \JVMW\JDK\bin\ (right next to the java.exe file).

Kind of a hack, but who cares...

(P.S. for those wondering, this solution does **not** need you to set -Dweblogic.management.allowPasswordEcho=true)